# spring boot application failed to autowired feign client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I created a sample project of Spring Boot to understand the Feign client functionality, when run it gives below error.

> Field remoteCallClient in com.example.demo.RestClient required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.RemoteCallClient' that could not be found.
> Action:
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.RemoteCallClient' in your configuration.

I tried various ways but it could not be resolved, provided the entire source code of the sample project.

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mictro-service-3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>micro-service-3</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Application's main class**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class MicroService3Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroService3Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Feign client**

```java
@FeignClient(url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",value="USERS")
public interface RemoteCallClient {
    
    @RequestMapping("users")
    public String getUsers();
}
```

**Rest controller**

```java
@RestController
public class RestClient {

    @Autowired
    private RemoteCallClient remoteCallClient;
            
        public String getRemoteClient() {
            return remoteCallClient.getUsers();
        }
    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
2018-07-23 11:22:57.668  INFO 6556 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4efbca5a: startup date [Mon Jul 23 11:22:57 PDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-23 11:22:57.852  INFO 6556 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-07-23 11:22:57.877  INFO 6556 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62660f56] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-07-23 11:22:58.066  INFO 6556 --- [           main] c.example.demo.MicroService3Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-23 11:22:58.075  INFO 6556 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6b58b9e9: startup date [Mon Jul 23 11:22:58 PDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4efbca5a
2018-07-23 11:22:58.712  INFO 6556 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=27c00c1a-419a-35b3-9b1b-f3a4f9bbf439
2018-07-23 11:22:58.726  INFO 6556 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-07-23 11:22:58.800  INFO 6556 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62660f56] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-23 11:22:58.992  INFO 6556 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-07-23 11:22:59.006  INFO 6556 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-23 11:22:59.006  INFO 6556 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-07-23 11:22:59.009  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\apache-tomcat\bin\;F:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;;E:\eclipse\oxygen\eclipse;;.]
2018-07-23 11:22:59.165  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-23 11:22:59.165  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1090 ms
2018-07-23 11:22:59.371  WARN 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-07-23 11:22:59.371  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-07-23 11:22:59.379  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@156f04f8
2018-07-23 11:23:00.180  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-07-23 11:23:00.183  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-23 11:23:00.184  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-23 11:23:00.184  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-23 11:23:00.184  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-23 11:23:00.184  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-23 11:23:00.184  INFO 6556 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-23 11:23:00.209  WARN 6556 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restClient': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'remoteCallClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.RemoteCallClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2018-07-23 11:23:00.210  WARN 6556 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name 'eurekaRegistration': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2018-07-23 11:23:00.212  INFO 6556 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-07-23 11:23:00.225  INFO 6556 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-23 11:23:00.353 ERROR 6556 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field remoteCallClient in com.example.demo.RestClient required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.RemoteCallClient' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.RemoteCallClient' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/899

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use below Feign Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 20):

For those, who included the Openfeign dependency and the feign client still cannot be autowired...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You have to also include the [`@EnableFeignClients`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.3.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/feign/EnableFeignClients.html) configuration annotation which scans for the `@FeignClient` interfaces. Otherwise these clients remain ignored.

```
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding @EnableFeignClients solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Make sure RemoteCallClient is not in different package than main application class. if it is added @ComponentScan("package")

Answer (score 0):

I was battling the similar issue. I see that you already have spring-cloud-starter-openfeign dependency. I recommend that you **remove** the older feign dependency that exists in your POM **spring-cloud-starter-feign 1.4.5.RELEASE**. If your feignClient resides in a different app then upgrade both apps to be on similar to be on same versions. That worked for me. Hope it works for you!

I am using 
spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.2.RELEASE 
spring-cloud-dependencies Greenwich.RELEASE
and have the following in my dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```